# Unique factorization for the semigroup generated by {2cos(π/n) | n>3}?

Tags: nt.number-theory, subfactors, factorization, exponential-sums, cyclotomic-fields

Let $S$ be the multiplicative semigroup of numbers generated by $B=\{ 2cos(\frac{\pi}{n}) \mid n \ge 4 \}$.

*Question*: Does every number of $S$ factorize uniquely (up to perm.) as a product of elements in $B$?

Note that $2cos(\frac{\pi}{n}) = e^{\frac{i\pi}{n}} + e^{\frac{-i\pi}{n}}$, so we can *reformulate* the question as follows.
Let  $4 \le n_1 \le \cdots \le n_r$ and  $4 \le  m_1 \le \cdots \le m_s$  such that $$ \sum_{(\epsilon_1, \dots,\epsilon_r) \in \{\pm 1\}^r} e^{i\pi (\sum_{k=1}^r\frac{\epsilon_k}{n_k})} = \sum_{(\epsilon_1, \dots,\epsilon_s) \in \{\pm 1\}^s} e^{i\pi (\sum_{k=1}^s\frac{\epsilon_k}{m_k})}$$
Then, is it true that $r=s$ and  $n_k = m_k , \forall k$?

Comment: I believe the answer is yes. One can write $2 \cos(\pi/n) = e^{-2 \pi i/(4n)} \cdot \frac{1 - e^{4 \pi i / n}}{1 - e^{2 \pi i / n}}$. In 1966, Bass determined all the multiplicative relations (modulo roots of unity) of expressions of the form $1 - e^{2 \pi i a / n}$. (See the paper "Generators and relations for cyclotomic units".)